# Unresolved function or method connect() mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

I am learning Mongoose from JavaScript Everywhere book, and this is the code I had to write:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = {
  connect: DB_HOST => {
    mongoose.connect(DB_HOST);
    mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
      console.error(err);
      console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.');
      process.exit();
    });
  },
  close: () => {
    mongoose.connection.close();
  }
}
```

when i hover over `connect` and `connection`, it shows `Unresolved function or method connect()` and `Unresolved variable connection` accordingly. My guess is that the book about an older version of mongoose, and in the newest version it is simply removed. What is the new function and variable for it?

Comment: It's not removed, see the example on the [Mongoose homepage](https://mongoosejs.com/). Have you actually tried running the code?

Comment: @robertklep yes, I ran it, but is there a way to solve this warning?

Comment: Fix your editor.

Comment: @robertklep, thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also learning Mongoose and have the same situation as you; here's how I fixed my error – you can use it as a reference to fix your code:

```
const {connect: connect1} = require('mongoose')

async function connect() {
    try {
        await connect1('DB_HOST')

        console.log('\n Connected successfully')
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('\n Disconnect')

    }
}

module.exports = { connect }
```

Comment: That's not a fix, that's a hack required to work around a bad editor.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's been some time.

replace your mongoose require with this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose').default;
```

should solve it for WebStorm

Still, I'd recommand using [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) instead